# Ground state of two fermions coupled with one boson

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises

I have an Hamiltonian of the form:

\begin{align}
\begin{aligned} H _ { 1 } & = f _ { 1 } \otimes b ^ { \dagger } + f _ { 1 } ^ { \dagger } \otimes b \\ H _ { 2 } & = f _ { 2 } \otimes b ^ { \dagger } + f _ { 2 } ^ { \dagger } \otimes b \\ H _ { 3 } & = 2 b ^ { \dagger } b - 3 f _ { 1 } ^ { \dagger } f _ { 1 } - 7 f _ { 2 } ^ { \dagger } f _ { 2 } \end{aligned}
\end{align}

which describes two fermions coupled to the boson, but not coupled to each other. $f_{1,2}^{\dagger}$ are the creation operators of the fermions $b^{\dagger}$ is that of the boson.

My question is: Is the ground state for $H_3$: 
\begin{align}
| G \rangle = \prod _ { i = 1 } ^ { 3 } \left( a _ { i } ^ { \dagger } \right) ^ { n _ { i } } | \phi \rangle \quad \text { with } \quad a _ { i } = \left\{ b , f _ { 1 } , f _ { 2 } \right\} \quad \text{?}
\end{align}
And how can I find from there the ground state with perturbation theory up to first order, taking $H= H_3 + \lambda (H_1 + H_2) $. I'm familiar with perturbation theory, but I'm quite confused how to deal with Hamiltonians with Tensor products.

Comment: Look at the signs in $H_3$: You get the lowest energy
for lowest number of bosons and highest number of fermions.

Comment: So do you mean $2n_b - 3n_{f_1}- 7 n_{f_2} = E_n^{(0)}$ and from there trying to solve \begin{align}
| \psi _ { n } ^ { ( 1 ) } \rangle = \sum _ { k \neq n } \frac { \left\langle \psi _ { k } ^ { ( 0 ) } \left| H ^ { ( 1 ) } \right| \psi _ { n } ^ { ( 0 ) } \right\rangle } { E _ { n } ^ { ( 0 ) } - E _ { k } ^ { ( 0 ) } } | \psi _ { k } ^ { ( 0 ) } \rangle
\end{align} But how do I calculate $\langle G | H_1 + H_2| G \rangle$?

Comment: Yes, the first line is what I mean. Lowest $n_b$ is $0$,
and the highest $n_{f_1}$ and $n_{f_2}$ are $1$ (because they are fermions).
So you have the ground state $|G\rangle = |0,1,1\rangle$.
Calculating $\langle G | H_1 + H_2| G \rangle$ then will be simple arithmetics.

Comment: Your Hamiltonian doesn't seem to be even order product of fermion operators to model a real physical scenario. Keeping this aside. Note that your Hamiltonian conserves, number of excitations ($f_{1}^\dagger f_{1}^{}+f_{2}^\dagger f_{2}^{}+ b_{}^\dagger b_{}^{}$), this should be helpful in finding exact ground state.

Comment: @ThomasFritsch I have calculated everything like you said. Thanks again for your comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the comments above I present here my solution. To find the ground state in first order perturbation theory, first one has to realize that ground state energy is \begin{align}
E _ { n } ^ { ( 0 ) } = 2 n _ { b } - 3 n _ { f _ { 1 } } - 7 n _ { f _ { 2 } } = - 10
\end{align}
The state is defined in perturbation theory as
\begin{align}
| G _ { n } ^ { ( 1 ) } \rangle = \sum _ { k \neq n } \frac { \left\langle G _ { n } ^ { ( 0 ) } \left| H ^ { ( 1 ) } \right| G _ { k } ^ { ( 0 ) } \right\rangle } { E _ { n } ^ { ( 0 ) } - E _ { k } ^ { ( 0 ) } } | G _ { k } ^ { ( 0 ) } \rangle
\end{align}
and therefore one can simply calculate: \begin{align}
\begin{aligned} \sum _ { k \neq n } \frac { \left\langle G _ { n } ^ { ( 0 ) } \left| H ^ { ( 1 ) } \right| G _ { k } ^ { ( 0 ) } \right\rangle } { E _ { n } ^ { ( 0 ) } - E _ { k } ^ { ( 0 ) } } | G _ { k } ^ { ( 0 ) } \rangle &= \sum _ { k \neq n } \frac { \left\langle G _ { n } ^ { ( 0 ) } \left| H _ { 1 } + H _ { 2 } \right| G _ { k } ^ { ( 0 ) } \right\rangle } { E _ { n } ^ { ( 0 ) } - E _ { k } ^ { ( 0 ) } } | G _ { k } ^ { ( 0 ) } \rangle\\&= \frac { \left\langle 0,1,1 \left| H _ { 1 } + H _ { 2 } \right| 1,1,1 \right\rangle } { - 10 + 8 } | 1,1,1 \rangle + \frac { \left\langle 0,1,1 \left| H _ { 1 } + H _ { 2 } \right| 0,0,1 \right\rangle } { - 10 + 7 } | 0,0,1 \rangle \\ & + \frac { \left\langle 0,1,1 \left| H _ { 1 } + H _ { 2 } \right| 0,1,0 \right\rangle } { - 10 + 3 } | 0,1,0 \rangle + \frac { \left\langle 0,1,1 \left| H _ { 1 } + H _ { 2 } \right| 0,0,0 \right\rangle } { - 10 - 0 } | 1,0,1 \rangle \\ & + \frac { \left\langle 0,1,1 \left| H _ { 1 } + H _ { 2 } \right| 1,1,0 \right\rangle } { - 10 - 2 } | 1,0,0 \rangle + \frac { \left\langle 0,1,1 \left| H _ { 1 } + H _ { 2 } \right| 1,0,1 \right\rangle } { - 10 + 4 } | 1,0,1 \rangle \\ & + \frac { \left\langle 0,1,1 \left| H _ { 1 } + H _ { 2 } \right| 1,1,0 \right\rangle } { | 1,1,0 \rangle } \end{aligned} \tag{1} \label{eq:11:2}
\end{align}
One can see that only terms will survive that have an excited state which goes to the ground state after applying one of the following operator:\begin{align}
\mathrm { I.f } _ { 1 } \otimes \mathrm { b } ^ { \dagger } \rightarrow | + 1 , - 1,0 \rangle , \text { II. } \mathrm { f } _ { 1 } ^ { \dagger } \otimes \mathrm { b } \rightarrow | - 1 , + 1,0 \rangle
\end{align}
\begin{align}
\text { III. } f _ { 2 } \otimes b ^ { \dagger } \rightarrow | + 1,0 , - 1 \rangle , \text { IV.f } _ { 2 } ^ { \dagger } \otimes b \rightarrow | - 1,0 , + 1 \rangle
\end{align}
    This means only the  6. term in Eq. \eqref{eq:11:2} will contribute if applied by II. and IV. applied on  7. give also a term. Hence the state is 
$$ | G ^ { ( 1 ) } \rangle = - \frac { 1 } { 5 } | 1,0,1 \rangle - \frac { 1 } { 9 } | 1,1,0 \rangle $$